# Android app sanity tests with appium using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, automated-tests, appium

My experience of writing tests has been with casperjs JavaScript. Now I have to do android app test automation using appium. I have gone through many tutorials but unable to create my first test using JavaScript with appium.
Anyone out there can help me creating my first test.

P.S. I have installed android studio and andriod SDK tools, set ANDRIOD_HOME and PATH environment variables. Downloaded [https://github.com/acolby/Testdroid_Example.git](https://github.com/appium/javascript-workshop) `npm install` run successfully but stuck while running `npm install -g mocha` and getting error

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mocha"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/CHANGELOG.md' 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/Projects/careaxiom/hfp-acceptance-tests/android/Testdroid_Example/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: why are u doing 'npm install -g mocha'

Comment: I'm following this [link](http://testdroid.com/news/appium-tip-6-jazzing-javascript-with-node-js) and it's written there to use 'npm install -g mocha'

Comment: try opening cmd prompt as 'Run as Administrator' and hit these commands. if doesnt works try adding sudo befor these commands

Comment: thanks @karthick23 command run with sudo. but when I run mocha ios_safari.js below error has produced `

  ios safari
pulling public devices from testdroid api...
OH NOOO!!! error: 
 { error: 'invalid_grant',
  error_description: 'Authentication failure in User Management' } 
 ... exiting, goodbye!
`

Comment: Kindly upvote if it solved ur prob in Android and try to add additional tags 'ios' to get help. ASFIK its not that straightforward with iOS @Farhat

Answer (score 1):

try opening cmd prompt as 'Run as Administrator' and hit these commands. if doesnt works try adding `sudo` befor these commands

Comment: Problem not yet solved. This Error coming 
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/utils.js:628
        throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '" + path + "'");
              ^
Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) 'ios_safari.java'
    at Object.lookupFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/utils.js:628:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:326:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:325:6)

......

    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
`

when I run command mocha ios_safari.js